# Проверить введенные данные пользователя с данными из файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Не знаю как проверить веденные данные пользователя что бы сравнились с строками из файла. Проблема заключается в одной функции GetIntoTheSystem. проверяет только одну строчку, что нужно дописать-переписать что бы проверялась не только первая строчка файла.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void EnterFild(string &, string &);
void DisplayMenu();
void AdminMenu();
void Registration();
void GetIntoTheSystem(string, string);

int main() {
 string userlogin;
 string userpassword;

 DisplayMenu();
 GetIntoTheSystem(userlogin, userpassword);

 return 0;
 }

 void EnterFild(string &userlogin, string &userpassword) {
 cout << "Enter the login: ";
 cin >> userlogin;

cout << "Enter the password: ";
cin >> userpassword;
  }

void Registration() {
  string userlogin, userpassword;

   EnterFild(userlogin, userpassword);

   ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open("program.txt", ios_base::app);
   outFile << userlogin << " " << userpassword << endl;
   outFile.close();

   cout << "\n\n";
  }

void AdminMenu() {
   ifstream insidFile("program.txt", ios_base::in);
   string line;

if (insidFile.is_open()) {
    int qtyuser = 1;
    while (!insidFile.eof()) {
        getline(insidFile, line);
        cout << "\t#" << qtyuser++ << ": " << line << endl;
    }
}
else {
    cerr << "Error, couldn't be opened the file." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  }

  void GetIntoTheSystem(string userlogin, string userpassword) {
ifstream isUserloginTrue("program.txt", ios_base::in);

string  line; int verify;
string  loginAdministrator = "Admin",
    passwordAdministrator = "Admin";

EnterFild(userlogin, userpassword);

if (isUserloginTrue.is_open()) {
    while (!isUserloginTrue.eof()) {
        getline(isUserloginTrue, line);

        if (line == userlogin + " " + userpassword) {
            cout << "WELCOME, " << userlogin << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (userlogin == loginAdministrator && userpassword == passwordAdministrator) {
            cout << "You have been enter as administrator!" << endl;
            cout << " - DISPLAY USERS: " << endl;
            AdminMenu();
            break;
        }
        else {
            for (int verify = 0; verify < 3; verify++) {
                cout << "\nUncorrect login or password.\n\tAttempts to enter left " << 3 - verify << endl;
                EnterFild(userlogin, userpassword);

                if (line == userlogin + " " + userpassword) {
                    cout << "WELCOME, " << userlogin << endl;
                }
                else if (userlogin == loginAdministrator && userpassword == passwordAdministrator) {
                    cout << "You have been enter as administrator!" << endl;
                    cout << " - DISPLAY USERS: " << endl;
                    AdminMenu();
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    if (verify == 2) {
                        cout << "\n\nAccess denied!The number of attempts is limited!\n\n\n" << endl;
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    cerr << "Error, couldn't be opened the file." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}

void DisplayMenu() {
  string userlogin, userpassword;
  int command = 0;

do {
    cout << "1. Log in system" << endl;
    cout << "2. Registration" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "\tPlease select your option(1-3): ";
    cin >> command;

    switch (command) {
    case 1: GetIntoTheSystem(userlogin, userpassword); break;
    case 2: Registration(); break;
    case 3: exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); break;
    }
  } while (command != 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас там серьезная проблема с алгоритмом, который реализован в функции GetIntoTheSystem. Вы смешали в одну большую кучу следующие вещи:

1. Предоставление пользователю нескольких попыток ввода;
2. Проверку введенных пользователем данных на наличие в файле паролей;
3. Проверку, не является ли пользователь администратором.

Причем, смешали неправильно. Все очень запутанно, местами нет необходимых break и т.д.

Работоспособная схема могла бы выглядеть так:

```
for(...) // цикл по попыткам ввода
{
    Ввести данные от пользователя;
    if(введенные данные соответствуют данным администратора)
    {
        Залогинить пользователя как администратора;
        return;    
    }
    else
    {
        Открыть файл паролей;
        while(файл паролей не закончился)
        {
            Считать строку
            if(строка соответствует введенным пользователем данным)
            {
                залогинить пользователя как обычного пользователя
                return;
            }
        }
        Закрыть файл паролей
        Вывести сообщение о неудаче авторизации.
    }
}
Вывести сообщение об исчерпании числа попыток авторизации.
```

Отмечу также, что предложенная схема лишь представляет собой минимальную модификацию вашего кода, чтобы он работал так, как вы ожидаете. И она не является идеальной ни с алгоритмической точки зрения (чтение файла каждый раз, последовательный поиск в нем), ни с точки зрения защиты информации (пароли в открытом виде в файле, ну вы поняли...).

И вообще, в предоставленном вами коде масса проблем с многих точек зрения. Но ладно. Тратить на это время не имеет смысла, пока вы не научитесь составлять работоспособные алгоритмы.